# How to add a tag when creating a work-item with az cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli, az

I'd like to create a product backlog item with tag by using the az cli (devops).

Creating the PBI works fine (az boards work-item create --type 'product backlog item' --title 'my pbi' -d 'some desc' --area  --iteration ). However, the cli does not offer something like a tag option.

Is there way to add a tag while creating the PBI, or by executing a subsequent az command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Azure Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/boards/work-item?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-boards-work-item-create) show you can use the `--fields` flag when calling `az boards work-item create` this enables you to use any of the fields defined on your work item.

For tags this field is System.Tags so you can add that to your command like this

`--fields "System.Tags=Foo"`

If you want a list of tags pass them as a comma separated list:

`--fields "System.Tags=Foo, Bar"`